# iOS Web App Title meta tag: Only Supports 12 Characters But Web App Titles Support 13 Characters

Tags: ios6, mobile-safari, meta-tags, safari

I am using the undocumented iOS Web App Title meta tag (available in iOS 6).

I placed the meta tag in the head of my HTML5 file and uploaded it to my web server. The title of my web page is "iOS Mobile Web App Title Meta Tag Test" but I used the iOS Web App Title meta tag like so:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="0123456789123">
```

When I open Safari on iOS 6 and add my web app to the homescreen the title reads "012345678912" --- it's dropping the last character (I can manually add the last character). Why is this? I tried it with regular text too (just in case the numbers were the problem).

Answer (score 0):

There's a size limitation to twelve characters because thats the name shown under your webapp icon on the user's "Desktop".

Comment: The size limit is 13 characters. Try adding a website to your iOS' Home screen and enter 0123456789123. All 13 characters show! BUT when you use <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="0123456789123"> the last character is dropped!